# Recuperar datos borrados en SugarCRM

Tags: mysql, crm, sugarcrm

estoy tratando de recuperar casos borrados en Sugar y hacer una traza de cual usuario los borro. No estoy seguro si los datos aún existen. He encontrado esta información, pero hasta el momento no ha sido de mucha ayuda:

1. http://blog.innovsystems.com/sugarcrm/how-retrieve-deleted-records-sugarcrm - No logro que funcione.
2. https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/21135 - Este hilo muestra una consulta, que tampoco funciona para mi caso.

También he tratado de entender como se hace el borrado y he tratado esto, lo que retorna ciertos resultados, pero aún no lo que me interesa:

```
SELECT cases.id, cases.name, users.first_name, users.title, cases.date_modified 
FROM cases
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = cases.modified_user_id
WHERE cases.deleted=1 ORDER BY cases.name ASC;
```

Veo que el sugar tiene una configuración para purgar las tablas cada mes (en mi caso).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber si alguien conoce como encontrar los casos borrados, con trazabilidad de quien lo hizo o si en el caso que expongo, definitivamente los casos ya no existen, por lo que no se podrían recuperar.